# The cleanup of old, bad questions is costing me votes!

Tags: discussion, voting

At least, [I think it's costing me votes.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120567/why-am-i-losing-votes)  My understanding is that when questions are deleted, votes cast on the Q or any As are taken out of a person's vote counts.

That's actually not a terrible thing, all the cleanup is worthwhile and I don't *really* hold the ones that @WesleyDavid initiated against him.  (The heartless jerk!)  And I'm still making progress towards being the top voter of all SE sites.

But after I posted the question linked above on meta.SO, someone pointed out another recent meta.SO post suggesting that [votes on deleted questions not be taken out.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117846/votes-cast-should-include-votes-on-deleted-contributions)  I think that's a good idea and I encourage anyone who agrees to express their support.  (and help me get my missing votes back!)

Got some good (and some not so good) discussion of this on meta.SO after I posted another question:

[Does the vote abuse algorithm roll back valid votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120595/does-the-vote-abuse-algorithm-roll-back-valid-votes)

Comment: Votes on deleted questions and answers don't count towards your headline figures.

Comment: @Iain I don't think he's questioning that. I think he's asking us to support the linked meta post that's asking for a reversal of that behavior.

Comment: @MDMarra: I've done the support thing :) I was just confirming Ward's suspicions too.

Comment: I'd also like to know when and how often the vote counts are re-done.  It seems like they mostly disappear at 0000 UTC on Saturday.

Comment: @Ward I think It's later than that, some time around 03:00UTC on Saturday. I have occasionally used all my votes on old closed questions between 00:00UTC and 01:00UTC Saturday and I've had them all back at 08:00UTC.

Comment: Sorry but to me you're sounding a bit like a two year old who was just told he has to share his sweets with his little brother.

Comment: @JohnGardeniers And you sound like you need to lighten up and recognize tongue-in-cheek comments when you see them.  (Hint: I don't *really* think WesleyDavid is a heartless jerk.)

Comment: @Ward, perhaps throw a smiley or two in there next time if you don't want us to take you seriously. I saw nothing hinting at humour. I was also talking about the entire post, not just the comment about WesleyDavid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter if @WesleyDavid is unsympathetic and heartless - He's a ***cat***(head)!

I do know that a lot of the questions we're wiping out will be taking some votes (mostly downvotes) with them, but they are pretty awful questions.  I also generally agree with wiping out votes for questions / answers that are deleted, though I could get behind a "ghost votes" count ("votes" showing votes on questions/answers that are still around, and "ghost votes" being a separate total that just covers deleted questions/answers.

I proposed something along those lines in the mSO discussion about this -- we'll see if it gets any legs.